# Check security mode of connected Wi-Fi network

Tags: command-line, wireless, security

How do I check the security mode of the connected Wi-Fi network, using the [command-line interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)?

I want to know whether the current Wi-Fi connection is protected with [WPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access), protected with [WEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy), or is an open network.

Comment: If this is not your network (and even if it's your, in general), it doesn't matter if the wifi network uses some protection — it should not be trusted anyway…

Comment: I would have suggested `iwconfig`, but then realized that on my WPA2 protected network it says `Encryption key:off`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got it! :)

```
sudo wpa_cli status
```

command gives me information exactly that I want.

```
Selected interface 'wlan0'
bssid=80:1f:72:95:d2:b2
ssid=whatever
id=0
mode=station
pairwise_cipher=CCMP
group_cipher=TKIP
key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
wpa_state=COMPLETED
ip_address=192.25.27.111
address=a4:4f:31:15:5f:44
uuid=6099d6ff-4b7d-538a-9e69-3479e250e401
```

Output of that command is easy to grep.

Answer (score 4):

You can try below command from CLI to list SSIDs.

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Or you can also use

```
nmcli -f all dev wifi | grep SSID | awk '{ print $1 " - " $9 }'
```

or

```
nmcli -f all dev wifi | awk '/SSID/{ print $1 " - " $9}'
```

replace SSID with ssid you need information for.

Comment: No, this command gives me informations about all wifi networks around. Second command is little more helpful but output of that command is confusing when I'm using it in script.

Comment: I added awk part so it will give you only relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

Please open a terminal and run:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Your network will appear, along with others in range, similar to this example:

```
Cell 04 - Address: xx:C1:50:78:B7:xx
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"ATT630"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000021823cba79
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4340ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

So we see that the encryption is WPA and WPA2 mixed mode with TKIP.

Comment: No, this command gives me informations about all wifi networks around. I want only information about connected wifi. Output of searched command will be used in script.

Answer (score -3):

- Click on the Wifi Icon on the top right corner.
- Then click edit connections
- Select the SSID and click edit
- Go to security tab.
- You will the find it there.

thank you

Comment: Welcome to ask ubuntu, the OP is asking for a way to see this information on the command-line rather than through the GUI.

Comment: @Arronical Got it !!!